# Как в кастомном ListView заменить layout для выбранного элемента?

Tags: android, android-layout

Всем добрый вечер!
Встал вопрос. Есть кастомный ListView итемы которого заполняются по одному макету. Вопрос как изменить макет для выбранного элемента listView на другой, то есть при щелчке чтобы он заполнялся по другому Layout'у? 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про селекторы и состояния. Единожды задав свойства layout для всех состояний Больше не придется морочить себе голову в адаптере

Comment: Может дадите ссылочку?

Comment: Я знаю как использовать селектор для изменения состояния кнопок и других виджетов! А как это сделать для Layout&

Comment: Конечно дадим ссылочку, https://code.google.com/p/iosched/

если скачать эту прилагу и глянуть там какраз список в котором выставляется куча состояний. вообще очень многое можно почерпнуть из этого примера))

Answer (score 0):

Если он кастомный, в чем проблема? делаете в методе getView() кейсы с необходимыми условиями, а в каждом кейсе уже делаете inflate для нужного лайаута

Comment: Может дадите пример? Я имею ввиду замену адаптера для выделенного элемента ListView.

Comment: фишка в том, что Вы не "заменяете", а просто по запросу адаптера отдаете правильный. посмотрите на свой код в getView.